# Sending notifications to thousands of tags (tag = User ID)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-notificationhub

I'm registering users by setting the UserId (Guid) as the tag. And I have to send notifications to thousands of them (from an MVC backend).

What I'm doing *-and not satisfied with-* is:

```
foreach(var tag in allTags) 
{
    hub.SendIos(tag); // without awaiting
    hub.SendGcm(tag); // without awaiting
    hub.SendWp(tag); // without awaiting
}
```

It works ONLY IF the users are not so much, otherwise, something goes wrong.
And I understand how many tasks or HttpClients are being created.

What is the best practice to do that?

Note: I couldn't have a better design to have all those users in one tag, the system design doesn't help.

Comment: Is there a reason you are sending notifications to a single device at a time? The whole point of tags is to target multiple devices. I know using a GUID to target a single device is good sometimes, but it seems like that might not be the best way in this case. Not able to suggest something better without knowing what devices you are trying to target. How are you collecting your `allTags` list? The whole point of Azure is to offload the work onto them so you do not have to do major processing like you are doing above.

Comment: I create and fill allTags in the runtime and it holds all users IDs that pass certain conditions, that's why I couldn't give them a special tag when the phones are being registered.

Comment: And I assume you could not assign the tags based on the conditions when the phones register?

Comment: @hvaughan3, unfortunately not, there are complex calculations to collect users.

Comment: Maybe there is a sense to offload push sending to the mobile app backend?  Once allTags is defined, invoke the Post action and pass it to that?

Comment: Have you looked into [notification templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-send-localized-breaking-news/)? That would at least make it so you did not have to send to iOS, GCM, and Wp separately. It would just become a single request and Azure would handle which type of device would get it.

Comment: @AlexBelotserkovskiy, I think there is a limitation of how many tags to send per SendX call, it's 20 tags maybe, that's why I send separately for each tag.

Comment: @hvaughan3, Yes I did, and I think it's time to give it a try. Thanks for helping..